# How can child inherit parents's background in ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, background-color

I have view which handles navigation inside parent view. Parent view has background colour, and I want to set child navigation view to not have background colour (I want to see parent's background colour).

I tried setting background colour of child view to transparent, and opacity to 0, but nothing is working, as in these cases I am getting that background colour of child view is white.

Is it possible to do this?

View which is used for Background:

```
const AppBackground = () => {
  return (
    <View {...StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
      <LinearGradient {...viewStyles.splash} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AppBackground;
```

Parent screen:

```
export default function BaseScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        ...viewStyles.verticallyCenteredContainer,
      }}
    >
      <Backgrounds.App />
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignSelf: "stretch",
        }}
      >
        <QuestionnarFormularNavigator />
      </View>

      <View {...viewStyles.bottomContainer}>
        <View {...viewStyles.horizontallySpacedContainer}>
          <Buttons.GoLeftButton
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TherapyType")}
          />
          <Buttons.GoRightButton
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("UnitsType")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

First screen from QuestionnareFormularNavigator (Diabetes Screen):

```
export default function DiabetesTypeScreen() {
  return (
    <View {...viewStyles.verticallyCenteredContainer}>
      <View style={{ height: 64 }} />
      <Labels.QuestionnaireTitle
        text={localizedStrings.labels.DiabetesTypeTitle}
      />
      <View style={{ height: 48 }} />

      <View {...viewStyles.verticallyStretchContainer}>
        <Lists.Questionnaire
          data={MockedData.DiabetesType}
          onPress={(id) => console.log(id)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

So when I try set opacity or background color of *Diabetes screen*, it goes white, and no `<Background.App />` from the parent view is visible under the *Diabetes screen*.

On request, I am adding code for:

*verticallyCenteredContainer*:

```
  verticallyCenteredContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
```

*Background.App*:

```
const AppBackground = () => {
  return (
    <View {...StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
      <LinearGradient {...viewStyles.splash} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried so far.

Comment: Added code, without imports as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Show your viewStyles.verticallyCenteredContainer and Backgrounds.App styles

Comment: Added that code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can give all components as children to Background.app.

Background.App:

```
const AppBackground = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <View {...StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
      <LinearGradient {...viewStyles.splash}>
          {children}
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
};
```

On the parent screen, you can use like this.

```
export default function BaseScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Backgrounds.App>
    <View
      style={{
        ...viewStyles.verticallyCenteredContainer,
      }}
    >
      
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignSelf: "stretch",
        }}
      >
        <QuestionnarFormularNavigator />
      </View>

      <View {...viewStyles.bottomContainer}>
        <View {...viewStyles.horizontallySpacedContainer}>
          <Buttons.GoLeftButton
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TherapyType")}
          />
          <Buttons.GoRightButton
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("UnitsType")}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    </Backgrounds.App>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution.
All I need is to set style for nested (child) navigator by using the following code:

```
  <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
      }}
    >
```

Comment: Could you use `"inherit"` instead of `"transparent"`?

Comment: I am not aware of propery `inherit` in React Native. What does it do?

Comment: It means you inherit the property value (in this case background colour) of the parent or enclosing element.  I tried it instead of "transparent" and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Save the style in a `variable` then use it in your `Parrent Component` then pass it as `props` to the `child Component`.

Comment: That will not do, as background is the gradient colour which goes from top to the bottom of the screen, and child view does not have the size of the whole screen.